# Problems migrating Virtualbox VM from one ubuntu server to another

Tags: 64-bit, virtualbox, kernel

I have recently bought a new faster server and so I want to start migrating things over to the new server. Having my email server (zimbra) installed in a virtual machine I figured it should be piece of cake, just move the .vdi, configure the new VM and enjoy the improved performance. Unfortunately I get a kernel panic on the new box when trying to boot:

[image: Kernel Panic]

Any ideas on what could be causing this? Could it be related to new host being 64-bit?

Some info on server1 (working):

Virtualbox version: `3.2.12r68302`

uname -a: `Linux server1 2.6.32-34-generic-pae #77-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 13 21:16:18 UTC 2011 i686 GNU/Linux`

Some info on server2 (Not working):

Virtualbox version: `4.1.6r74727`

uname -a: `Linux server2 2.6.32-33-server #72-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 29 21:21:55 UTC 2011 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer ended up being really simple. I had to activate ioapic in the settings on the new host.